# Negative Coefficients in Polynomial time Complexity

Tags: complexity-theory

Assuming some algorithm has a polynomial time complexity **T(n)**, is it possible for any of the terms to have a negative coefficient? Intuitively, the answer seems like an obvious "No" since there is no part of any algorithm that reduces the existing amount of time taken by previous steps but I want to be certain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When talking about polynomial complexity, only the coefficient with the highest degree counts.

But I think you can have T(n) = n*n - n = n*(n-1). The n-1 would represent something you don't do on the first or last iteration.

Anyway, the complexity would still be n*n.

Comment: The second part of your answer is exactly what I was looking for. It IS possible for a polynomial time complexity to have a negative coefficient while still maintaining both the fact that at each step it is only adding to the time taken. The example was very demonstrative.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible for an algorithm to have a negative coefficient in its time complexity, but overall the algorithm will have some positive time complexity. As an [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Example) from Wikipedia, take the function `f(x)=6x^4-2x^3+5`. They solve for the complexity of `O(x^4)` as follows:

> [image]
>
> for some suitable choice of x0 and M and for all x > x0. To prove this, let x0 = 1 and M = 13. Then, for all x > x0:
>
> [image]
>
> So,
>
> [image]

That is, even if there are negative coefficients in the original equation, there is still some positive overall time complexity based on the term with the highest order of power.

---

What about for lower bounds? By definition, we can find the lower bound of any function by using the following [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations): As `n` goes to infinity, then for some constant `k` and some `n0` we have that the following holds for all `n>n0`:

> [image]

Let's guess that the above function f(x) is also Omega(x^4). This means that:

> 6x^4 - 2x^3 + 5 >= kx^4

Solving for k:

> k <= (6x^4 - 2x^3 + 5)/(x^4)
>
> k <= 6 - 2x^-1 + 5x^-4

The term (2/x) approaches 0, as does (5/x^4) so we can choose `k=2` for some large x0=30. To show that this holds, we show that:

> 6x^4 - 2x^3 + 5 >= 2x^4 where x > 30
>
> 4x^4 - 2x^3 + 5 >= 0

Which holds. So `f(x)` is Omega(x^4), and we can also conclude that we have found a tight bound such that `f(x)` is Theta(x^4).

Why does this work, even though the coefficient was negative? For both Big O and Big Omega notation, we are looking for a bound such that *after some point* one function dominates another. That is, [as these graphs illustrate](https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~Alistair.Rendell/Teaching/apac_comp3600/module1/growth_of_functions.xhtml):

> [image]
>   <sub>(source: [Alistair.Rendell at cs.anu.edu.au](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~Alistair.Rendell/Teaching/apac_comp3600/module1/images/Introduction_BigOGraph.png))</sub>
>     -- Big O
>
> [image]
>   <sub>(source: [Alistair.Rendell at cs.anu.edu.au](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~Alistair.Rendell/Teaching/apac_comp3600/module1/images/Introduction_BigOmegaGraph.png))</sub>
>    -- Big Omega

Thinking about our original f(x), `6x^4`grows faster than `2x^4` (our kg(x) function). After *some point*, the `6x^4` term will outstrip the growth of `2x^4` in such a way that it is always greater than `2x^4`. Graphically, the two functions look like this:

[image]

Despite the negative coefficient, clearly `kg(x)` is a lower bound of `f(x)`.

---

Now, is this always true for any polynomial function with any negative coefficient--that a function `f(x)` with any coefficients will be bound by its highest degree polynomials? No. If the term with the highest degree has the negative coefficient, then the bounds aren't quite the same. Take `f(x) = -2x^2`. We can show that `f(x) = O(x^2)`:

> -2x^2 <= cx^2
>   -2 <= c

Which can be satisfied by any `c>0` (as `c` is by definition a positive constant). However, if we try to do the same for lower bound:

> -2x^2 >= cx^2
>   -2 <= c

Then we can't find the right `c` because again `c` must be non-negative.

Comment: Great example. However, I found proving a lower bound a lot more difficult. The example is for the big-o of the polynomial time function but what if you also wanted to prove the lower-bound? How would you go about doing that?

Comment: @betsegaw let me work on the example--in short, it should also work but I'll do a write up for you

Comment: I am just seeing this after a long time. Thank you for the detailed explanation(I only saw your initial explanation the first time). I always knew that the highest term would need to have a positive coefficient but I couldn't figure out how to show that it can be bound below too. But now I can see how you can also show it for a _specific_ polynomial,I am going to try it for a general polynomial.