# Time complexity of algorithm with number of operations described by polynomial of more than one variable

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I know that a certain algorithm I am using does `2Nk - 4k^2` operations, with parameters `N` and `k`. Now, the first derivative of that function is `2N - 8k` (I know that `N` and `k` can only be positive integers here, but bear with me). That derivative is positive when `k < N/4` and negative when `k > N/4`. So the complexity actually reduces if we increase `k` past a certain point. How will I express this in Big O notation? Also note that `k <= (N - 1)/2`, so there is an upper bound on `k`.

**NOTE:**

I know that a similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243691/negative-coefficients-in-polynomial-time-complexity), but it does not consider the case where the first derivative changes sign if one of the variables reaches a certain point.

Comment: Note that the derivate you've posted is only a partial derivative for how your function grows w.r.t. parameter `k`. In the asymptotic region (as we are studying _asymptotic_ behaviour of the function), naturally the function will always decrease w.r.t. growing `k` (so for counting "number of iterations" for a fixed `N`, the algorithm is `O(1)` w.r.t. asymptotic `k`, as `numIt>=0`). On the other hand, the function will naturally grow w.r.t. growing `N`. These two describe two separate asymptotic studies of the independent growth of one of the variables, with the other one fixed. ...

Comment: ... If attempting to use big-O notation for a function of two independently varying variables, [we can generally not use the classic definition of big-O notation](http://people.cis.ksu.edu/~rhowell/asymptotic.pdf). Hence, **(A)** either study the asymptotic behaviour for two different cases: 1. growth of `N` with `k` fixed and 2. vice versa, or **(b)** look into the specifics of how to use big-O notation for function of two independently growing variables, which is not as simple as the "regular" 1-variable big-O analysis.

Comment: @dfri regarding the partial derivative and keeping the other variable fixed, I did take that into account. I did not anticipate that SO users would require such detail :)

Comment: Since this question is in the area of pseudo-math.stackexchange.com, you're in corners of SO where rigour and detail is extra appreciated ;)

Comment: @dfri regarding your second comment: since we always use big O notation for asymptotic behaviour, does it make it inappropriate to use big O for variables that are bounded from above?

Comment: It kind of depends: the asymptotic behaviour needn't refer to the behaviour of some function, say `f(n)`, for _"huge values of `n`"_, but rather for _"sufficiently large values of `n`"_. E.g., for some function `f(n)` we might refer to the asymptotic behaviour for all `n>1000`, whereas `n` is, say, bounded from above to avoid integer overflow (say `18446744073709551615` for an `UInt64`). If some variable in a multi-variable function, say `f(n,m)`, is bounded from above (say `m<M`), then we could treat it as a constant, `m=M`, to find the upper asym. bound of `f(n,M)` w.r.t. growing `n`.

Comment: I see, so in the case of the algorithm I have here its probably best to analyse the behaviour of increasing `k` for `k > N/4` and `k < N/4` separately (keeping `N` constant at some high value), since `N/4` is the point where the behaviour changes for `k`